# Fixed Width Sidebars with Dynamic Content

Tags: html, css, layout, fluid-layout

http://jsfiddle.net/uCwEz/

I need to have three divs, with the first and last div (red and blue) having a fixed width, and the middle div (green) dynamically changing its width to fit perfectly between the outside divs as the page width is adjusted. In the jsFiddle, I've accomplished this with the fixed-width first div and content adjusting, and I've floated the third div right, but it needs to slide up into the empty space you see next to the main div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `#div3` between `#div1` and `#div2` in your HTML.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <div id="div3">   
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
</div>​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/uCwEz/2/